# How to work out a percentage for total sales

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am having difficulty getting a percentage for total sales on a report. The report has a summary box with a list of the various departments and there sales so far. I want to get a percentage for each department based on the total sales in the blank column shown.

[image: report]

This is the matrix at the design stage.

[image: design]

I have found a few questions on here that show various expressions to do this, but I have not been able to get the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: Could you point us to the solutions that have not worked?

Comment: @Schmocken too numerous to list...Am i right that the expression should be going in the box above the highlighted one on the 2nd picture? I have read people saying use the 'total' box for the formula, but do not understand what this means.

Comment: One more question: would you be amenable to performing the calculation in your code?

Comment: @Schmocken No, has to be done at report level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try:
1. Identify the name of your sales total, ie the cell with 25 million in. [TextBoxA]
2. Write the expression =Sum(Fields!Sales_Nett_Local.Value) / ReportItems![TextBoxA].Value
3. Change your cell property to percentage.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. I had used a similar method earlier, but obviously not correctly. I have just managed to get it working using this method as well `=SUM(Fields!Sales_Nett_Local.Value)/SUM(Fields!Sales_Nett_Local.Value,"HPPSummarySales")` however, I don't understand why this works. Isn't it dividing the same values(the total)?

Comment: The left half of the expression is summing your group ie Board. The right half is summing all values in your data set (because you have defined the entire data set as being in scope with "HPPSummarySales")  ie Board, Doors, Fittings...